# Visual tools for documenting MVC projects?

Tags: model-view-controller, documentation

I have recently started using *Coldbox* and *Kohana* frameworks in my projects, but cannot make my mind about a visual tool to document the project. I am using *Visual Paradigm* (UML) and *yEd* (free-form), but will be happy to try something else if it makes capturing MVC-like relationships among elements easier.

Any suggestion on **visual tools (and best practices) for documenting MVC projects** are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I like [Violet](http://alexdp.free.fr/violetumleditor/page.php) for UML modeling.  It's simple and lightweight, but gives me everything I need.  (I'm actually working on a big class diagram right now.)

Comment: @keithjgrant Thanks for this. In terms of MVC, what makes Violet better than the others?

Comment: It doesn't really have anything specific to MVC, but I've never really encountered that in a UML app.  What I like about it is it doesn't constrain you to any pre-conceived way of organization (other than basic UML standards), so you have the flexibility to do it whatever way works best for you.  If you prefer more structure,  this probably isn't the one for you.